# Redirecting in PHP and JS without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I am trying to make a web file server (a cloud). I decided to put a basic form password auth on `index.php`. When the user enters the password and clicks the button, JS sends that password to `index.php` and it decides if it correct.

If it is, then index.php redirects the user to `files.php`. If not, then refreshes the page.
I know that redirecting and refreshing is done through `header();`, but when I use this and watch the "Network" tab in my browser, it receives the `files.php` but doesn't load it (stays on `index.php`). I am sure the reason is header sent after some text (well, it is header).

How do I redirect user's browser to some page after current page been sent? Should I ask JS to do it? Then how? Here is my index.php:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
  echo '
   <h1>Hello World</h1>
   <form>
    <input name="password" type="text"></input>
    <button onclick=authClick() class="test" type="button"></button>
   </form>
  ';
  print_r($_POST);
  if ($pass == "123123") {
   header("Location: files.php");
  }
 ?>
 <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

And here goes the JS:

```
function authClick() {
 var editBox = document.querySelector('input');
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var body = 'password='+encodeURIComponent(editBox.value);
 xhr.open("POST","/index.php",true);
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
 xhr.send(body);
}

var myHeading = document.querySelector('h1');
myHeading.textContent = 'nigga';
b = document.querySelector('button');
b.setAttribute('content', 'test content');
b.setAttribute('class', 'btn');
b.innerHTML = 'submit';
```

Comment: Are you using a FORM? Can you provide some code?

Comment: Can we see the redirect code?

Comment: You might need ajax or cURL

Comment: Are you loading the content into the current DOM?

Comment: Using header in php and document.location.href in js will still refresh or reload.

Comment: @Deckerz `header("files.php");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Ajax, and the point of Ajax is to make an HTTP request **without loading a new page**.

Since you want to load a new page: Remove the JavaScript. Perform a regular form submission with a regular HTML submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Using Js you can write it as follows

```
window.open( response.data.url, '_blank');
```

If you want to open it directly in current tab

```
window.open( response.data.url );
```